# Why won't Malaysia's regions get colored?

Tags: javascript, geography

I want to create a colored map for Malaysia but the colors don't display. I've used the names from the file [my.js](http://www.gstatic.com/charts/regioncoder/0/geocodes/my.js) which works for other countries with google geochart. Why won't it work?

```
    function drawMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Province'],
            ['MY-SK'],
            ['MY-K'],
            ['MY-M'],
            ['wilayah persekutuan labuan'],
            ['wilayah persekutuan putrajaya'],
            ['negeri sembilan']
        ]);

        //var results = {"sarawak": "MY-SK", "melaka": "MY-M", "kedah": "MY-K", "wilayah persekutuan labuan": "MY-L", "wilayah persekutuan putrajaya": "MY-16", "negeri sembilan": "MY-N", "johor": "MY-J", "kelantan": "MY-D", "perlis": "MY-R", "sabah": "MY-SA", "wilayah persekutuan kuala lumpur": "MY-W", "pulau pinang": "MY-P", "terengganu": "MY-T", "pahang": "MY-C", "perak": "MY-A", "selangor": "MY-B"};


        var options = {
            region: 'MY',
            backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
            datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
            width: 468,
            height: 278,
            resolution: 'provinces',
        };
        var container = document.getElementById('mapcontainer');
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

        function myClickHandler() {
            var selection = chart.getSelection();
            var message = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                var item = selection[i];
                // if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
                message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}';
                //} else
                if (item.row != null) {
                    message += '{row:' + item.row + '}';
                    //} else if (item.column != null) {
                    //  message += '{column:' + item.column + '}';
                }
            }
            if (message == '') {
                message = 'nothing';
            }
            //alert('You selected ' + message);

        }
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['geochart'],
        callback: drawMap
    });
```

[image]

The regions that belong to Malaysia should get colored green as they do for other countries. Why don't they?

Comment: If you want an easy "fix," try changing `datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this kind of problem and though I don't have exact explanation why the problem happened, you can try this workaround to use the [ISO_3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:MY) representation of malaysian provinces rather than its name directly.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Province', 'Name'],
        ['MY-15', 'wilayah persekutuan labuan'],
        ['MY-16', 'wilayah persekutuan putrajaya'],
        ['MY-05', 'Negeri Sembilan']
    ]);
```